# calling a stored procedure to a class in visual studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, class, stored-procedures, windows-forms-designer

I wrote a simple stored procedure the **sp_insert** that would insert the data and **sp_Update** that would update the data then **sp_delete** that would delete data and **sp_search** that would search the data and last **sp_view** that would view the data into sql server its look like these [image]
 . I tested the stored procedure and it  executed fine.Now I'm already connect to the database Icon to my Vs2015 until I click to the test connection it's success then click Uk now its connected. look like these..

[image]

Now we are on  a windows form UI in my VS2015 C#. I am created a class I name it repository in solution Explorer in my project.these class I have a code here 
here it is..here is my  problem I can't call the four stored procedure which is the sp_insert,sp_Update,sp_delete,sp_search,sp_view in my class and its nothing to show.is there any problem regarding of my code.

```
public class repositories
    {
      //Initializes a new instance of the DataContext class by referencing     the connection name of database.
    public static DataClasses1DataContext db = null;

   //that registration is my table
    public static void add(registration)
    {
        db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
          //they are getting red cannot call sp_insert that i was created in sql server in my whole entire procedure.
        db.sp_insert(Username, password, securityQuestion, SecurityAnswer, LastName, firstName, MiddleInitial, address, gender, birthdate, age);
    }
    public static void Update (registration)
    {
        db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        db.sp_Update(Username, password, securityQuestion, SecurityAnswer, LastName, firstName, MiddleInitial, address, gender, birthdate, age);
    }
    public static void delete (registration)
    {
        db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        db.sp_Delete(UserId);
    }
    public static List<sp_ViewResult> View()
    {
        db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        List<sp_ViewResult> View() = db.sp_view().Tolist<sp_viewResult>(); 
    }


}

}
```

I need some guidance in doing so. Can anyone just help me..

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Pro tip: [Don't use the `sp_` prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Where did the code for `DataClasses1DataContext` come from?  Did you write it?  Was it generated from an EF?

Comment: @Jhon Wu thanks for comment but why.. that sp_ is created now from my sql server as a stored procedure.

Comment: Created by what?

Comment: the DataClasses1DataContext is calling the class of my database name when I'm highlight it it results 'class database' 'name.DataClasses1DataContext'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using entity framework and registration is an object which was not clarified in you question then this code should work.

Also make sure you have added your stored procedures in you entity framework model. If they are added you could have the error because you are not adding any values but the entire class.

> FYI. If you are running debug mode it should catch any error during
>   the process if not in a try catch however if you run release it may
>   not catch the error.

You may have to import using System; to use IDisposable

```
public class repositories: IDisposable
{
    private DataClasses1DataContext _db;
    public DataClasses1DataContext db
    {
        get
        {
            if (_db == null)
            {
                _db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            }

            return _db;
        }
    }

    public static void add(registration reg)
    {
        db.sp_insert(reg.Username, reg.password, reg.securityQuestion, reg.SecurityAnswer, reg.LastName, reg.firstName, reg.MiddleInitial, reg.address, reg.gender, reg.birthdate, reg.age);
    }
    public static void Update(registration reg)
    {
        db.sp_Update(reg.Username, reg.password, reg.securityQuestion, reg.SecurityAnswer, reg.LastName, reg.firstName, reg.MiddleInitial, reg.address, reg.gender, reg.birthdate, reg.age);
    }
    public static void delete(registration reg)
    {
        db.sp_Delete(reg.UserId);
    }
    public static List<sp_ViewResult> View()
    {
        List<sp_ViewResult> View() = db.sp_view().Tolist<sp_viewResult>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. it can call now if we add a reg in registration

Comment: what are the uses in getting like this                      private DataClasses1DataContext _db;
 public DataClasses1DataContext db

Comment: the fields are really works but the all the db. on public static void add,update,delete,view was not accessible or error